# Symfony 2 : Swiftmailer exception

Tags: email, symfony, swiftmailer

I've been working on the Symfony 2 emails sending using Swiftmailer.

Here is my swiftmailer configuration in app/config/config.yml

```
swiftmailer:
 transport: gmail
 username:  myusername@gmail.com
 host:      smtp.gmail.com
 password:  mypassword
```

I have also configured my xampp localhost to send emails.

I have a form where user enters email addresses (max 5 emails) , Subject and Message. For first few tests on submitting the form the emails where sent. I also actually got emails. But after that i've been getting this error below repeatedly.

> Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "myusername@gmail.com" using 1 possible authenticators
>   500 Internal Server Error - Swift_TransportException

What is the problem over here? I also tried stopping my xampp and then re-starting it, but still the problem persists. Does any one know whats the problem here?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're facing this issue because you haven't properly setup your mailing host. 
First off, I strongly recommend that you use a service such as [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com) and configure it as detailed in this [Symfony2 Mailing Setup Tutorial](http://intelligentbee.com/blog/2015/12/02/send-emails-in-symfony2-the-right-way/):

```
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: smtp.sendgrid.net
mailer_user: your_sendgrid_username
mailer_password: 'your_sendgrid_password'
mailer_port: 587
```

The tutorial also contains details on how to properly setup a mailing service in Symfony2 and how to build mailing templates.

But you if you still want to use Gmail, then the correct configuration is:

```
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
mailer_user: your_gmail_address@gmail.com
mailer_password: 'your_gmail_password'
mailer_port: 587
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember `host` value is ignored, when `transport` is set to `gmail`. Regarding your issue, make sure that you are using latest version of SwiftMailer (v4.1.5), because there it has been fixed. From changelog:

- prevented stream_socket_client() from generating an error and throw a Swift_TransportException instead

In general, if authentication fails, an Exception of type `Swift_TransportException` will 
be thrown.